# Webelement screenshot error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, bufferedimage

With the below code i try to capture the screenshot of WebElement with selenium webdriver.

```
    WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/div[2]/div/div[2]")); 
        File screenshot1 = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        BufferedImage  fullImg1 = ImageIO.read(screenshot1);
         Point point1 = ele1.getLocation();
         int eleWidth1 = ele1.getSize().getWidth();
         int eleHeight1 = ele1.getSize().getHeight();
         BufferedImage eleScreenshot1= fullImg1.getSubimage(point1.getX(),  point1.getY(), eleWidth1,
                    eleHeight1);
         ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot1, "png", screenshot1);
         File screenshotLocation1 = new File("D:/personalloan.png");
         FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot1, screens

hotLocation1);
```

But, this gives the error

(y + height) is outside of Raster

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: Error is (y + height) is outside of Raster

Answer (score 0):

i face this kind of problem while i used appium. There, i need to rotate the element. but when i use this code, it will take screenshot of element which will not rotated and this problem occurs. so i fixed the problem by telling appium to always open image in landscape mode.

i think some thing like this is happening also in u. when u inspect manually, it is in a form but when code works it is in different form.

so please check ur element y co ordinate properly.

Comment: But, I am taking screenshot of a webelement not an Image